# How to join a VAR with a table from the model?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a VAR (named **VarTable**), which is just a transformation of an original table in the model.

Then I want to return it as:

RETURN ADDCOLUMNS(**VarTable**,  LOOKUPVALUE(Employee[Name],Employee[Key], VarTable[Key])

But it doesn’t work... neither does using ‘RELATED’.

My question is: how do you join two tables, (one from the model and the other one being just a VAR created inside the measure/calculated table)?

Comment: Try to change the key column name in VarTable to be different from original table, and use it without table name - [NewKey] for example, instead VarTable[NewKey].

Comment: https://dax.guide/naturalinnerjoin/